# C# Winforms How to Update a Form (loading screen) before calling Application.Run()

Tags: c#, winforms

**Scenario** I have a splash screen with a marque progressbar that is suppose to animate, indicating to the user that programming is initializing and starting up.

This (splashscreen) form is the first thing to start off - even before Application.Run(theMainForm).

**Question:** How do I update this splash screen to enable functionality (such as the animated progress bar).

**Note** I'm aware that Application.Run() is the message loop/pump for windows and that is NOT my question

Comment: I hope this link will help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955663/how-to-build-splash-screen-in-windows-forms-application#comment9734517_7955844

Answer (score 2):

You can put it in its own thread starting from Application.Run, take a look: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C