# Maximized window doesn't show after splashscreen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application with a splashscreen. When the splashscreen disappears, the window opens maximizend for a fraction of a second and then my application goes back to the background (like it's minimized). Why does this happen? My form has `WindowState = Maximized` enabled.

```
public Main()
{
    //Splashscreen and new window
    initializeWindow();
}

 public void SplashScreen()
{
    Application.Run(new SplashScreen());
}

 private void initializeWindow()
{
    //Start new Thread which shows Splash Screen
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashScreen));
    t.Start();
    //Wait 3 seconds
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    InitializeComponent();
    //Initialize form
    t.Abort();
    //Abort and make main form the top form
    //TopMost = true; <-- I commented this because it makes other applications not open unless if I minimize the window
}
```

Comment: [Right way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15836105/1997232) of doing splash-screen. ["Left" way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32469582/1997232) (the one you are using as it seems).

Comment: [Show Splash Screen during Loading the Main Form](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32421479/3110834)

Answer (score 2):

Pausing the main thread is not a "healthy" solution , I would advice to do this :

1. Instead of opening the Main window open the splash screen form.
2. In the splash screen form set a timer that closes it.
3. In the `FormClosed` event of the splash screen open the Main window.