# Splash screen - winforms vs. WPF ? VS 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, splash-screen

In browsing MSDN I saw that one could easily create a Splash-screen by importing an image file & setting the Build Action to 'Splash Screen'.

Is this only for a WPF or can I do the same for a Windows Form application?

Answer (score 2):

No you can not do it for a Windows Form the same way that you did in WPF.

[How to build splash screen in windows forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955663/how-to-build-splash-screen-in-windows-forms-application)