# After loading the form that should be showed up is automatically closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem regarding the loading screen I've created.

I execute the code run but after the progress bar is finished, the form is shown but closes automatically.

Why is this happening?

```
namespace LogIn 
{

    public partial class Loading : Form
    {
        public Loading()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Increment(2);
            if (progressBar1.Value == 100) timer1.Stop();
            if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
            {
                this.Close();
                Login Login = new Login();
                Login.ShowDialog();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think that `this.Close()` is doing?

Comment: If you are showing Loading as your main application form then, when you call close, it closes the form, and hence ends the application. In your main, you probably have the line 'Application.Start(Loading)' or similar.

Comment: oh!! thank you!! i use it as my main form! thank you!! now i know that
if main form(this.close();) is similar to Application.Exit();
THANKYOU!

Comment: I don't think they are simliar, this.Close() just ends the message loop of the form Loading, it still runs in the static method Main, if there are more code in that method (after the Application.Run(new Loading())), the code will be executed while Application.Exit() will terminate the application at once. They are different. =))

Comment: @KingKing You are absolutely correct in that they aren't the same - you are right, too, any code after the Application.Run will execute before the application ends. The *effects* are similar, though, in the usual case (i.e. no code after the Application.Run).

Answer (score 2):

In your startup code (your Main method), you probably have something like the following:

```
Application.Run(new Loading());
```

This makes `Loading` your [main Application Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.mainform.aspx). When you call `Close`, you are closing Loading, which effectively ends the application.

What you are really looking for is the concept of a [Splash Screen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lF7vHWVJbk0).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955663/how-to-build-splash-screen-in-windows-forms-application) and related answers for an overview.

Answer (score 0):

Check your form Login.Visible property, after Login.ShowDialog(); Make it true. Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).