# Creating a borderless/topmost/transparent splash window in Monogame?

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm trying to create a splash window like many applications and games use. The effect I'm trying to create looks like this: [FL Studio Splash Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ETlJ.png)

Essentially, I want to create a borderless, transparent window in Monogame and draw a texture over it. I also need the window to show on the topmost layer of windows on the screen (optional, but preferred).

How can I create that transparent window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Monogame` is used for cross-platform projects, I don't know if `Monogame` has a built-in the splashscreen class or function.

The method you're asking sound like you wish it to work on windows platform.

You can achieve it on windows in 2 ways:

1. Using `WPF`, you can use [Splash Screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.splashscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. Using `Windows Forms` Create a border-less window and show it. See [How to build splash screen in windows forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955663/how-to-build-splash-screen-in-windows-forms-application) and change the [Form.TransparencyKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the color which you want it to be shown as transparent.

Comment: Great answer. I'm sure it would be possible to do it on most platforms, but I think it'd be a custom implementation for each one.