# C# Show Windows Form before executing the code

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

this maybe a stupid question but I can't find a solution after some googling.
I want to perform a code directly after executing a Windows Forms application in C# and Visual Studio. However if I do this my WindowsForm is opening after the code was (correctly) executed. Is there any way to accomplish that the form is shown while executing the code? The reason behind it is that I want to show a progress bar.

Best regards,

Timtam

Comment: You can use Form.Shown  event for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955663/how-to-build-splash-screen-in-windows-forms-application