# loading screen in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, loading, sleep

I'm trying to use a loading gif image for a loading screen in windows form I want the loading screen to show up for 5 seconds I am trying to implement that with thread.sleep() function but the problem was everything stops in the current winForm includes the gif image itself.
I want to delay the 5 seconds of loading time with the animated gif image working

Comment: Please update your question to include the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Thread.Sleep() blocks the current thread. You should use a timer or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to use `Thread.Sleep` due to the problems you are describing. `Thread.Sleep` is almost never the correct answer in a UI program.

What you want to use is a [timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317088/why-there-are-5-versions-of-timer-classes-in-net) that raises an event after 5s and then stops itself, or use [`await Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-6.0) that wraps a timer internally.

You also need to be careful to ensure that your [loading window does not become the main window of your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445009/splash-screen-and-main-window).

Answer (score 1):

Thread.Sleep() blocks the current thread (ie. the UI thread). You can use this wait method which uses a timer.

```
public void wait(int milliseconds)
{
    var timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    if (milliseconds == 0 || milliseconds < 0) return;

    timer1.Interval = milliseconds;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();

    timer1.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Stop();
    };

    while (timer1.Enabled)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```