# How can I build a moveable splash form that should be closed when the main form is open?

Tags: c#, splash-screen

I followed the highest vote answer of this page ( [How to build splash screen in windows forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955663/how-to-build-splash-screen-in-windows-forms-application))to build my splash form. It worked, and it can close while the main form opened. But the splash form is not moveable in this case. How can I make it moveable?

Comment: Use [code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24691094/2330053) to make your borderless form moveable...

Comment: You can implement a mouse down event and use the mouse mouve event.