# Problem with the run of several applications - System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently in the development of a windows forms application and I am having a little problem that is blocking me completely.

My problem:
In the program.cs file I have the execution of a first form which allows me to check if the person is well connected to the Internet. Once the verification is done, I would like to close this form and open my application, I tried with `Application.Run(new App());`, but it tells me that I cannot do two starts in a thread.

```
// program.cs

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Loading());
        }

        public static bool CheckInternet()
        {
            try {
                using (var web = new WebClient())
                using (web.OpenRead("http://google.com"))
                    return true;
            } catch {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// loading.cs

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class Loading : Form
    {
        public Loading()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.text_version.Text = "0.0.0.1";

            if (Program.CheckInternet())
            {
                var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
                timer.Interval = 2000;

                timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    StartApp();
                };

                timer.Start();
            }
        }

        private void StartApp()
        {
            this.l_info.Text = "Starting app...";
            this.l_info.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 270);

            Application.Exit();

            Application.Run(new App()); // Error here
        }
    }
}
```

I hope explain it well. If you have any questions do not hesitate.

Thanks to anyone who will have the time to help me.

Comment: We will need a [mcve].

Comment: You can use `Someform.ShowDialog()` instead of `Application.Run(new SomeForm());`. Call `Application.Run(new MainForm());` after the Dialog is closed. If you really need a Form to check whether *the person is well connected to the Internet*, that is. I don't see why, but...

Comment: go ahead and include the exception/error as well, and perhaps update your question' title with a sentiment like "<this exception> is thrown when doing several Application.Run calls", that should improve this question

Comment: @Jimi I tried putting a `ShowDialog()` in front of `Application.run` but I still get the same error `System.InvalidOperationException`

Comment: what have you tried? have you tried moving `Application.Run(new App());` out of `StartApp` scope and below `Application.Run(new Loading());` in `Main`?

Comment: `var loadForm = new Loading(); if (loadForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { Application.Run(new App()); }`. -- Move everything related to the Internet test to the `Loading` Form (WebClient stuff included) and make `Loading` return `DialogResult.OK` if the test succeeds. -- Better with a `using` statement, but the Form is disposed anyway.

Comment: Ok, great @Jimi last comment works great. On the other hand my text which says that the application will launch this does not have time to be displayed I tried to make a sleep but it keeps the text defined by default in the form. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: When the `CheckInternet()` method returns (hoping it returns, none of the WebClient async methods accept a CancellationToken, so you probably want to use HttpClient instead, to abort the test after a TimeOut), start a Timer and close the Form in the Tick handler. In the `FormClosed` handler, remove the Tick event handler and dispose of the Timer (if it's not in a Component you have added in the Designer).

Comment: I'll say your issue is something worth noting, but what you're attempting to actually do here is covered in [How to build splash screen in windows forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955663/how-to-build-splash-screen-in-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various implementations you could do here for control flow (I think @jimi's comments on using `DialogResult` is a decent approach), but what's important is that you should not attempt to do a nested `Application.Run` call.

In this implementation, we'll close `Loading` `Form` which will continue the execution in `Main`. Note that doing `Application.Exit` also will continue execution in `Main`, but it won't actually `Run` any new forms.  As such, you do have a scenario where we can add that behavior (whether or not you actually intended to have this behavior is up to your requirements).

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   Application.Run(new Loading());
   Application.Run(new App());
}
```

Next,

we'll move `Application.Exit()` to the else-block of `Program.CheckInternet` conditional check.

we'll remove `Application.Run` from `StartApp`

we'll do `Close()` the `Loading` `Form` in the now improperly named `StartApp` function scope.

```
public Loading()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.text_version.Text = "0.0.0.1";

    if (Program.CheckInternet())
    {
        var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 2000;
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();
            StartApp();
        };

        timer.Start();
    } else {
        Application.Exit();
    }

}

private void StartApp()
{
    this.l_info.Text = "Starting app...";
    this.l_info.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 270);

    Close(); //this.Close for Form instance close, not Application.Exit
}
```

Comment: I modify it works correctly but still the same problem with the text which does not have time to change.

Comment: Otherwise I just thought I increase the time eg to 5000 and I check to 2000 and change to new text. Do you think this is a good thing?

Comment: Where as this answer is really intended to address the exception and demonstrate how you can successfully do Application.Run twice (running two separate form instances.. though not concurrently); the better implementation and approach for this splashscreen feature that relates to relating state/progress of starting the app, would be to use threading.

Comment: I look at the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=net-5.0

Comment: I try but I do not understand how the thread works as in the end it does not display the form until it is finished.

Comment: I see you marked this as an answer that is helpful.  I would like to comment that: though I do recognize this answer does not provide a working sample of what the OP is trying to (and yet to) achieve, I feel that what was observed and raised to question on does not necessitate a working example of that scope.   To be clear, the requirements and implementations will vary.

Comment: Apart from this snippet demonstrating (sequential Application.Run calls - that don't run concurrently or share/manage state).  there is threading as well as an `ApplicationContext` (encapsulating on Forms and managed states) implementations worth consideration.