# app launcher with option to choose physical screen

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-8.0

I couldn't get the button layout according to my screen layout (simulation using buttons).

[image]

I hope to be able to obtain the same distribution of buttons similar to the one existing on the screens.

instead I get this:

[image]

my script currently is this (The closest I have achieved to the final layout,):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WebStack_Deployer_for_Docker.Forms
{
    public partial class DisplaySelector : Form
    {
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
        {
            public int length;
            public int flags;
            public int showCmd;
            public POINT ptMinPosition;
            public POINT ptMaxPosition;
            public RECT rcNormalPosition;
        }

        public readonly int screens = Screen.AllScreens.Length;

        private Panel panelMonitors;

        private const int ButtonWidth = 160;

        private const int ButtonHeight = 100;

        public DisplaySelector()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeMonitorSelection();
        }

        private void InitializeMonitorSelection()
        {
            panelMonitors = new Panel
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };
            Controls.Add(panelMonitors);

            Screen[] allScreens = Screen.AllScreens;
            Array.Sort(allScreens, (a, b) => a.Bounds.X.CompareTo(b.Bounds.X));

            int totalScreens = allScreens.Length;

            int startX = (ClientSize.Width - totalScreens * (ButtonWidth + 20)) / 2;
            int startY = (ClientSize.Height - ButtonHeight) / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < totalScreens; i++)
            {
                int monitorIndex = i;
                Button monitorButton = new Button
                {
                    Text = $"Pantalla #{monitorIndex + 1}",
                    Tag = monitorIndex,
                    Size = new Size(ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight),
                    // Calcula la posición X y Y del botón de acuerdo a la disposición real de las pantallas
                    Location = CalculateButtonPosition(startX, startY, monitorIndex, totalScreens, ButtonWidth)
                };

                monitorButton.Click += MonitorButton_Click;
                panelMonitors.Controls.Add(monitorButton);
            }
        }

        private Point CalculateButtonPosition(int startX, int startY, int monitorIndex, int totalScreens, int buttonWidth)
        {

            int positionX = startX;
            if (monitorIndex > 0)
            {
                positionX += (buttonWidth + 20) * monitorIndex;
            }

            int positionY = startY;

            if (totalScreens > 1)
            {
                if (monitorIndex == 0)
                {
                    positionY -= ButtonHeight / 2 + 20;
                }
                else if (monitorIndex == totalScreens - 1)
                {
                    positionY += ButtonHeight / 2 + 20;
                }
            }

            return new Point(positionX, positionY);
        }

        private void MonitorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
            int monitorIndex = (int)clickedButton.Tag;
            MessageBox.Show($"Has seleccionado el Monitor #{monitorIndex}");
            MoveToDisplay(monitorIndex);
        }

        public static void MoveToDisplay(int display)
        {
            if (Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
            {
                IntPtr windowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

                WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT
                {
                    length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT))
                };
                GetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, ref placement);

                Rectangle secondMonitor = Screen.AllScreens[display].WorkingArea;
                int windowWidth = placement.rcNormalPosition.Right - placement.rcNormalPosition.Left;
                int windowHeight = placement.rcNormalPosition.Bottom - placement.rcNormalPosition.Top;
                int windowLeft = secondMonitor.Left + (secondMonitor.Width - windowWidth) / 2;
                int windowTop = secondMonitor.Top + (secondMonitor.Height - windowHeight) / 2;

                placement.rcNormalPosition.Left = windowLeft;
                placement.rcNormalPosition.Top = windowTop;
                placement.rcNormalPosition.Right = windowLeft + windowWidth;
                placement.rcNormalPosition.Bottom = windowTop + windowHeight;
                placement.showCmd = SW_SHOWNORMAL;

                SetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, ref placement);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);
    }
}
```

***Remarks:*** I am programming this in C#/winform for .net8.0 on a Windows 11 home PC.

***The problems detected that I have not been able to solve:***

- Order of the buttons.
- Button layout similar to the configuration established in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be simplified to not use P/Invoke perhaps. One solution you could experiment with is to create a rectangle representing the max bounds of the multi-screen working area, and scale it to fit within a cell of a `TableLayoutPanel`. By setting it to `Anchor.None` it will be automatically centered in the single cell of the TLP at which point buttons representing the individual screens can be added.

[image: windows control panel next to custom version]

When one of the buttons is clicked, copy the location and size of the display that has been clicked to the Main Form.

---

```cs
public partial class DisplaySelectorForm : Form
{
    public DisplaySelectorForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        var screens = Screen.AllScreens;

        var minLeft = screens.Min(screen => screen.WorkingArea.Left);
        var minTop = screens.Min(screen => screen.WorkingArea.Top);
        var maxRight = screens.Max(screen => screen.WorkingArea.Right);
        var maxBottom = screens.Max(screen => screen.WorkingArea.Bottom);
        var workspace = new Rectangle
        {
            Width = maxRight - minLeft,
            Height = maxBottom - minTop,
        };
        var scaleX = tableLayoutPanel.Width / (double)workspace.Width;
        var scaleY = tableLayoutPanel.Height / (double)workspace.Height;
        var scale = Math.Min(scaleX, scaleY); 
        workspace.Size = new Size((int)(workspace.Width * scale), (int)(workspace.Height * scale));

        var workspacePanel = new Panel
        {
            Size = workspace.Size,
            Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
            BackColor = Color.White,
        };

        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(workspacePanel, 0, 0);

        foreach (var screen in screens)
        {
            var screenLeft = screen.WorkingArea.Left - minLeft;
            var screenTop = screen.WorkingArea.Top - minTop;
            var screenScaledLeft = (int)(screenLeft * scale);
            var screenScaledTop = (int)(screenTop * scale);
            var screenScaledWidth = (int)(screen.WorkingArea.Width * scale);
            var screenScaledHeight = (int)(screen.WorkingArea.Height * scale);
            var screenButton = new Button
            {
                Text = $"Display {screens.ToList().IndexOf(screen) + 1}\n({screen.DeviceName})",
                Size = new Size(screenScaledWidth, screenScaledHeight),
                Location = new Point(screenScaledLeft, screenScaledTop),
                BackColor = screen.Primary ? Color.CornflowerBlue : Color.LightGray,
                Tag = screen,
            };
            screenButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if(
                    sender is Control control
                    &&
                    control.Tag is Screen selectedScreen
                    &&
                    Owner is MainForm mainForm)
                {
                    mainForm.Location = selectedScreen.WorkingArea.Location;
                    mainForm.Size = selectedScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                }
            };
            workspacePanel.Controls.Add(screenButton);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The main form code uses a technique to show the `DisplaySelectorForm` as a splash screen as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75534137/5438626).

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ = Handle;
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => execDisplaySelectionFlow()));
    }
    protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value) =>
        base.SetVisibleCore(value && _initialized);

    private void execDisplaySelectionFlow()
    {
        using (var selector = new DisplaySelectorForm())
        {
            selector.ShowDialog(this);
        }
        _initialized = true;
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        Show();
    }
    bool _initialized = false;
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/multi-display-diagram.git)

Comment: thanks, I selected it as an answer, but I also posted an issue on github: https://github.com/IVSoftware/multi-display-diagram/issues/1 related to the design/location of the buttons..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I see that the mobile screen attached through Spacedesk is shown, but with an incorrect relative size. I understand the issue but unfortunately have no way to reproduce it so I will speculate that it has to do with the relative screen densities that need to be taken into account in the scaling factor. Once this additional math is done I predict that the sizes would be "apples-to-apples".

Answer (score 1):

```
         private void InitializeMonitorSelection()
         {
             panelMonitors = new Panel
             {
                 Dock = DockStyle.Fill
             };
             Controls.Add(panelMonitors);
        
             Screen[] allScreens = Screen.AllScreens;
             Array.Sort(allScreens, (a, b) => a.Bounds.X.CompareTo(b.Bounds.X));
        
             int totalScreens = allScreens.Length;
        
             
             Rectangle a = Rectangle.Empty;
             foreach (var screen in allScreens)
             {
                 
                 if (MinX > screen.Bounds.X)
                 {
                     MinX = screen.Bounds.X;
                 }
                 if( MinY > screen.Bounds.Y)
                 {
                     MinY = screen.Bounds.Y;
                 }
             }
             
        
             for (int i = 0; i < totalScreens; i++)
             {
                 int monitorIndex = i;
                 Button monitorButton = new Button
                 {
                     Text = $"Pantalla #{monitorIndex + 1}",
                     Tag = monitorIndex,
                     Size = new Size(ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight),
                     // Calcula la posición X y Y del botón de acuerdo a la disposición real de las pantallas
                     Location = CalculateButtonPosition(allScreens, monitorIndex, ButtonWidth,ButtonHeight)
                 };
        
                 monitorButton.Click += MonitorButton_Click;
                 panelMonitors.Controls.Add(monitorButton);
             }
             // Centering the buttons
             for (int i = 0; i < allScreens.Length; i++)
             {
                 panelMonitors.Controls[i].Location = new Point(panelMonitors.Controls[i].Location.X + (this.ClientSize.Width - WidthForCenterig) / 2, panelMonitors.Controls[i].Location.Y + (this.ClientSize.Height - HeightForCenterig) / 2);
             }
         }
```

Calculate the positon X,Y for the button. `(allScreens[monitorIndex].Bounds.X - MinX)` Shift every monitor position so all position bigger then 0. Monitors can have minus position. `buttonHeight / allScreens[monitorIndex].Bounds.Height` this just scales the position to the buttonWidth. If some position is wrong try `monitorIndex-1`

```
         int MinX = int.MaxValue;
         int MinY = int.MaxValue;
         int WidthForCenterig = 0; int HeightForCenterig = 0;
         private Point CalculateButtonPosition(Screen[] allScreens, int monitorIndex,  int buttonWidth, int buttonHeight)
         {
        
            int positionX = (allScreens[monitorIndex].Bounds.X - MinX) * buttonWidth / allScreens[monitorIndex].Bounds.Width;
            int positionY = (allScreens[monitorIndex].Bounds.Y - MinY) * buttonHeight / allScreens[monitorIndex].Bounds.Height;
             if(WidthForCenterig < positionX + buttonWidth)
             {
                WidthForCenterig = positionX + buttonWidth;
             }
             if(HeightForCenterig < positionY + buttonHeight)
             {
                HeightForCenterig= positionY + buttonHeight;
             }
             return new Point(positionX, positionY);
         }
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer of what you have done?